# Node.js only allow connections with specific VPN

Tags: node.js, vpn

I am trying to make a simple Node.js app with the express npm package to only allow if you are connected to a specific VPN. Here's an example:

> I am connected to VPN *exampleVPN* and I am looking at **http://localhost:8080**, which sends me a 204 response.

But:

> If I am not connected to *exampleVPN* and go to **http://localhost:8080**, I get a 401 response.

I'm just starting out and I am not sure of the strategy to go with here.

My first guess is to only allow incoming requests from a specific VPN server through a middleware by whitelisting the VPN's IP but that seems janky and could bring up some issues down the line if the VPN's IP changes for whatever reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you need this? There may be other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: My brother-in-law (in sales dep.) is working remotely with a team and they are trying to find a more convenient way of looking at data than an excel sheet and they're using a work VPN which I wanted to take advantage of for restrictions. Any alternatives would do to.

Comment: Well if the server is only opened locally, and the port is not open to the internet, why can't anyone on the internal network simply use it?

Comment: I used localhost as an example but ultimately I thinking of using something like heroku to push the app and have that as the url.

Comment: I suppose if you didn't want to check IP's, you could store a key on both client and server and encrypt the data with the key so that only the server could decrypt it? Perhaps look at JSON Web Tokens, and instead of having the server encrypt a token, you could encrypt it (with an expiry)?